# How to reverse endianness?

Tags: c, endianness

Can someone help me understand this code?

```c
int reverse_endianess(int value) {
    int resultat = 0;
    char *source, *destination;
    int i;

    source = (char *) &value;
    destination = ((char *) &resultat) + sizeof(int);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
        *(--destination) = *(source++);
    return resultat;
}
```

I can't understand this part of code:

```c
destination = ((char *) &resultat) + sizeof(int);
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
    *(--destination) = *(source++);
```

Comment: This line `*(--destination) = *(source++);`  is changing the byte order of `value` , i.e. endianess

Comment: You can use [htonl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl).

Comment: @kichik It will only "reverse" on systems where the endianess *not* the same as network order. That is won't work on BE systems

Comment: Though the code looks correct, and the answers are good, I still want to add: it is better to use bitwise operations `<<`, `>>` ,`|`.  `&` instead of this approach. They both leave less concerns than type casts (see strict aliasing mentioned in comments of answers), and tend to optimize better (more likely to be compiled in a single cpu instruction).

Comment: This is not an efficient approach. Pure arithmetics one generates the best code as in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following causes `destination` to point to the byte that follows `resultat` (as long as `resultat` is an `int`):

```c
destination = ((char *) &resultat) + sizeof(int);
```

It could also have been written as follows:

```c
destination = (char *)(&resultat + 1);
```

---

The following is just a simple memory copy loop:

```c
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
        *(--destination) = *(source++);
```

It's equivalent to the following:

```c
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
   --destination;             // Point to the one byte earlier.
   *destination = *source;    // Copy one byte.
   source++;                  // Point to one byte later.
}
```

---

Program flow (assuming 32-bit `int` and 8-bit `char`)

After setup:

```
source               value
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | a | b | c | d |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |      ^
                +------+

destination          resultat 
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |                      ^
                +----------------------+
```

After one pass of the loop:

```
source               value
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | a | b | c | d |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |          ^
                +----------+

destination          resultat 
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | 0 | 0 | 0 | a |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |                  ^
                +------------------+
```

When it's done:

```
source               value
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | a | b | c | d |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |                      ^
                +----------------------+

destination          resultat 
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+
|        -------+    | d | c | b | a |
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+
                |      ^
                +------+
```

Comment: Isn't *writing* `int` as `char *` violating strict aliasing? I mean accessing something written as `char` array using `int` type.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. You would know better. If it is, it means this code isn't portable.

Comment: I think it is, a bit moot point for me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The code does not write `int` as `char *`. It writes it as `char`; the lvalues used are `char`, not `char *`. This is explicitly permitted by the aliasing rule in C 2018 6.5 7; it says “An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: … a character type.” “Access” in the C standard means reading or writing (C 2018 3.1: “access (verb) <execution-time action> to read or modify the value of an object”).

Comment: @EricPostpischil The `destination` is written as `char` array, but is accessed later on as `int` via `resultat`. This is where I meant the possible issue is.

Comment: @ikegami the problem is only the inefficiency of this code. Compilers even if the target has byte swap instructions will not use it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. memcpy would sort out the problem. Other problem is that compilers do not recognize it as byte wap operation and do not generate the appropriate instruction. That is IMO the main issue of this approach. The difference is seen in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Three different approaches. The first one is most efficient on the systems having byte reversing instructions.

```
#define SWAPUC(a,b) do{unsigned char temp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = temp;}while(0)

int reverse(int i)
{
    unsigned int val = i;

    if(sizeof(val) == 4)
        val = ((val & 0xff) << 24) | ((val & 0xff00) << 8) | ((val & 0xff0000) >> 8) | ((val & 0xff000000) >> 24);
    if(sizeof(val) == 8)
        val = ((val & 0x00000000000000ffULL) << 56) | ((val & 0xff00000000000000ULL) >> 56) |
              ((val & 0x000000000000ff00ULL) << 40) | ((val & 0x00ff000000000000ULL) >> 40) |
              ((val & 0x0000000000ff0000ULL) << 24) | ((val & 0x0000ff0000000000ULL) >> 24) |
              ((val & 0x00000000ff000000ULL) <<  8) | ((val & 0x000000ff00000000ULL) >> 8);
    
    return val;
}

int  reverse1(int val)
{
    union
    {
        unsigned i;
        unsigned char uc[sizeof(val)];
    }uni = {.i = val};

    if(sizeof(val) == 8)
    {
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[7], uni.uc[0]);
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[6], uni.uc[1]);
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[5], uni.uc[2]);
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[4], uni.uc[3]);
    }
    if(sizeof(val) == 4)
    {
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[3], uni.uc[0]);
        SWAPUC(uni.uc[2], uni.uc[1]);
    }
    return uni.i;
}

int reverse2(int val)
{
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(val)];
    memcpy(uc, &val, sizeof(uc));
    if(sizeof(val) == 8)
    {
        SWAPUC(uc[7], uc[0]);
        SWAPUC(uc[6], uc[1]);
        SWAPUC(uc[5], uc[2]);
        SWAPUC(uc[4], uc[3]);
    }
    if(sizeof(val) == 4)
    {
        SWAPUC(uc[3], uc[0]);
        SWAPUC(uc[2], uc[1]);
    }
    memcpy(&val, uc, sizeof(uc));
    return val;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%x\n", reverse2(0xaabbccdd));
}
```

The generated code (x86):

```
reverse:
        mov     eax, edi
        bswap   eax
        ret
reverse1:
        mov     eax, edi
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     ecx, edi
        shr     eax, 24
        movzx   esi, ch
        sal     ecx, 24
        mov     dl, al
        mov     eax, edi
        sal     esi, 16
        shr     eax, 16
        mov     dh, al
        movzx   eax, dx
        or      eax, esi
        or      eax, ecx
        ret
reverse2:
        mov     eax, edi
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     ecx, edi
        shr     eax, 24
        movzx   esi, ch
        sal     ecx, 24
        mov     dl, al
        mov     eax, edi
        sal     esi, 16
        shr     eax, 16
        mov     dh, al
        movzx   eax, dx
        or      eax, esi
        or      eax, ecx
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%x\n"
```

Or cortex M4 (this one has byte swapping instruction)

```
reverse:
        rev     r0, r0
        bx      lr
reverse1:
        mov     r3, r0
        lsrs    r2, r3, #24
        movs    r0, #0
        bfi     r0, r2, #0, #8
        ubfx    r2, r3, #16, #8
        bfi     r0, r2, #8, #8
        ubfx    r2, r3, #8, #8
        bfi     r0, r2, #16, #8
        bfi     r0, r3, #24, #8
        bx      lr
reverse2:
        mov     r3, r0
        lsrs    r2, r3, #24
        movs    r0, #0
        bfi     r0, r2, #0, #8
        ubfx    r2, r3, #16, #8
        bfi     r0, r2, #8, #8
        ubfx    r2, r3, #8, #8
        bfi     r0, r2, #16, #8
        bfi     r0, r3, #24, #8
        bx      lr
.LC0:
```

So the winner is the first function using only the bitwise arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say `sizeof(int) = 4` so 32 bit int.
A char is sizeof 1, 1 byte.
A normal int* looks like this:

```
aabbccdd // the int in hexadecimal
^ pointer points to start
```

If we cast it to a char*, we get `aa`. Thats whats done with `source`.

If we now add sizeof 4, we jump 4 bytes to the right:

```
aabbccdd?? 
                  ^
```

We are now one byte behind the value, accessing this may segfault the program or just read garbage. This does not happen due to the use of `--destination` instead of `destination--`. It is decremented first.
Now we just read the integer passed in from the front, while writing it from the back:

```
a1b2c3d4 // original int
->

d4c3b2a1 // destination
              <-
```

Note that two hexadecimal digits are one byte, which is why we dont get
`4d3c2b1a`. We leave the bytes in the correct way, but put the first bytes last.

Comment: Thanks, That was so helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was using this for a very long time.
data is a pointer to value to be reversed
n is the number of char to be reversed; usually 2, 4, 8 for short, int, long long.
 But this can be different on various architectures/OS

```
void SwapEndianN(char *data, unsigned short n) {
  unsigned short k; char c;
  for ( k=0 ; k < (n/2) ;k++ ) {
    c = *(data+((n-1)-k));
    *(data+((n-1)-k)) = *(data+k);
    *(data+k) = c;
  }
}
```